# typescript loop inside promises return final counter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, es6-promise

Im doing a loop with promises and want to return the final counter, the thing is that when I check the counter inside is correct, but when I check the value resolved is always 0.

so here is the idea

```
let tempFinalResult: number

export function finalRecount(): Promise<number> {
  tempIssues = 0 // Restart the counter on call the function
  return new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
    getStoredValues().then((resultsFound) => {
      resultsFound.forEach((query) => {
        fetchValuesFromQuery(query.query) // call external api for get values
          .then((queryResults) => {
            console.log(
              'Values found' +
                queryResults.values.length // This is working founds the data
            )
            tempFinalResult += queryResults.values.length
          })
          .catch((err) => {})
      })
      console.log('Total values ' + tempFinalResult) // oh oh the values are 0
      resolve(tempFinalResult)
    })
  })
}
```

Now when I call the function

```
finalRecount.then((counter) => {
  console.log(counter) // Is 0 !!
})
```

Comment: Yes, that's how Promises work, they are asynchronous. You are doing a series of asynchronous operations inside the callback of an asynchronous operation, and still expecting the result of the whole thing synchronously :) It just won't work with this `.then().then().forEach( .then())` nightmare. Drop all the `.then()` literature and convert everything to `async/await`, otherwise IMO that's a lost cause.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call